# Sending mails with attach php file which fetch data from database

Tags: php, mysql, email

when am trying to send multiple mails with the php file attachment which fetch the data from database, after sent successfully mails I am getting blank link in invite.php file when it reach in gmail, that means after sent the mail php file not fetching the data from database so it's not showing any link but all other contents are showing well and in localhost php link showing correct

This is my code

index.php

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['invite'])) {
foreach($_POST['invite'] as $check) {
    }
$import_emails =  implode($_POST['invite'], ',');
$imp_eml = explode(',', $import_emails); 

foreach ($imp_eml as $addr)
{
$mail->AddBCC($addr);
}  
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body = file_get_contents('invite.php');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->From = 'info@myweb.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Someone';
$mail->Host = '********';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = '*******';
$mail->Password = '*******';

if($mail->Send())
{
 echo "success";
} else {
 echo "failure";
} 
}
?>
```

invite.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php")
$customerid = $_REQUEST['customerId']; //comming from another page

$query = mysql_query("select * from  table where customerId = '$customerid'");
 while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 $prjid = $fetch['projectId'];
 }
?>
Vote for my projects <?php echo '<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/project-details/'.$c_id.'/'.$p_id.'/">here</a>'; ?>.<br/>
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/project-details/<?php echo $c_id.'/'.$p_id.'/'; ?>"><?php echo 'http://www.mywebsite.com/project-details/'.$c_id.'/'.$p_id.'/'; ?></a>
?>
```

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 3):

`file_get_contents()` will only get contents of file (surprise :) ). To execute it you have to use `include` or `require` and catch results with `ob_*()`.

I think it'll be better to create function which will return that links as string to avoid using output buffering.

About output buffering you can read here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: sorry but i don't know about ob_*() so can you explain or can you provide me link for it. Thank You

Comment: @ShubhamVema Read updated answer. Part about using function instead too :)

Answer (score 0):

**I found one solution. Try this**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');
if (!$con)
{
    die("error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$filename = "email_data";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM email_data order by id asc limit 0,100");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$filename2='datas/'.$filename.'.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename2, "w");
$seperator = "";
$comma = "";
foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $name);$comma = ",";}
$seperator .= "\n";
$seperator;
fputs($fp, $seperator);
mysqli_data_seek($sql, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $value);$comma = ",";}
    $seperator .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $seperator);
}

fclose($fp);

$my_file = $filename2;
$path = "datas/";
$from_name = "solomon";
$from_mail = "pss@gmail.com";
$mailto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$message = "Hi,\r\n do you got attachment?\r\n\r\Solomon";
$replyto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$file = $my_file;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";
mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)

?>
```